# Function not displaying and updating DOM element as it supposed to do

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

Following a course while building an simple banking app as an example of DOM manipulation, I encountered a problem where my very simple function wont update HTML snippet so there fore the updated value wont display on the screen app. Here is my function and HTML snippet. Think its not necessary providing CSS code before there is nothing of interest to the problem there.

Code from Java Script (actual function):

```js
const labelSumIn = document.querySelector('.summary__value--in');
const labelSumOut = document.querySelector('.summary__value--out'); //elements defined at the top of code

calcDisplaySummary = function (movements) {
    const incomes = movements.filter(mov => mov > 0).reduce((ak, cur) => ak + cur, 0);
    labelSumIn.textContent = `${incomes}€`;
    const out = movements.filter(mov => mov < 0).reduce((ak, cur) => ak + cur, 0);
    labelSumOut.textContent = `${out}€`;
};

calcDisplaySummary([1,-1,2,-3]); //function call`
```

```html
SUMMARY -->
<div class="summary">
    <p class="summary__label">In</p>
    <p class="summary__value summary__value--in">0000€</p>
    <p class="summary__label">Out</p>
    <p class="summary__value summary__value--out">0000€</p>
    <p class="summary__label">Interest</p>
    <p class="summary__value summary__value--interest">0000€</p>
    <button class="btn--sort">&downarrow; SORT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask what specifically isn't working? In your demo the `--in` and `--out` elements are populated (`3€`, and `-4€` respectively); what else should be happening that isn't happening? I will add that the `&downarrow` should be `&darr`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in input argument of `calcDisplaySummary`. `account.movements` is not defined in your snippet and therefore I can't know for sure what is the problem, but if you manually call `calcDisplaySummary` with fixed values (e.g.: `calcDisplaySummary([1, 2, -4, -6, -7])`) then you can see the update on the screen. Try to log the `account.movements` before you call the function and this will bring you one step closer to the solution.

```js
const labelSumIn = document.querySelector('.summary__value--in');
const labelSumOut = document.querySelector('.summary__value--out'); //elements defined at the top of code

calcDisplaySummary = function (movements) {
    const incomes = movements.filter(mov => mov > 0).reduce((ak, cur) => ak + cur, 0);
    labelSumIn.textContent = `${incomes}€`;
    const out = movements.filter(mov => mov < 0).reduce((ak, cur) => ak + cur, 0);
    labelSumOut.textContent = `${out}€`;
};

// calcDisplaySummary(account.movements); // <-- here is your problem
calcDisplaySummary([1,2,-4,-6,-7]);
```

```html
<div class="summary">
    <p class="summary__label">In</p>
    <p class="summary__value summary__value--in">0000€</p>
    <p class="summary__label">Out</p>
    <p class="summary__value summary__value--out">0000€</p>
    <p class="summary__label">Interest</p>
    <p class="summary__value summary__value--interest">0000€</p>
    <button class="btn--sort">&downarrow; SORT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well source of input data is not a problem so far as I logged it into console: 

const account3 = {
  owner: 'Steven Thomas Williams',
  movements: [200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460],
  interestRate: 0.7,
  pin: 3333,
};

However I got reference error on all my elements that I picked up from HTML in the very top of JavaScript file. Idk why is that! The other functions works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically problem is solved by disabling "strict mode". Still I do not know why its working in "casual" mode...Some explanation would be good...All consts are defined in the function outer scope and are available for functions scopes...